# SQL nested Inner Joins? Or Where Clause On Inner Joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am having an issue with a query I am trying to write.  Unfortunately I can only query against the database and cannot change the schema. Here are some simplified example tables:

```
Table 1
itemID          sale date
----------------------------
1                 1/2015
1                 3/2016
2                 5/2016
2                 1/2015

Table 2
itemID           colorID           price
--------------------------------------
1                 1                23
1                 2                10
1                 3                13
2                 1                11
2                 2                14
2                 3                18

Table 3
ColorID       color
---------------------------------------
 1             Red
 2             Blue
 3             Green

Table 4
SaleBegin       SaleEnd      ColorID
----------------------------------------
1/1/2014        12/31/2014      1
1/1/2015        12/31/2015      2
1/1/2016        12/31/2016      3
```

Now I need a query that essentially gets the price and color for both item ids in the first table.  I'm not sure how to do it with this schema even just for one. I tried something like:

```
SELECT item_id, price, color FROM Table1 T1

INNER JOIN Table2 T2
ON T1.ItemID=T2.ItemID

INNER JOIN Table3 T3
ON T2.ColorID=T3.ColorID

INNER JOIN  Table4 T4
ON T3.ColorID=T4.ColorID

WHERE T1.itemID between SaleBegin AND SaleEnd
```

But it's not working for me, instead giving me every possible color and price for each item.  What am I doing wrong?  How do I get those values? Expected results should look like:

```
    itemID     color      price  
------------------------------------
    1           Blue        10
    1           Green       13
    2           Green       18
    2           Blue        14
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `WHERE T1.SaleDate between SaleBegin AND SaleEnd`?

Comment: are you trying to find the price and color for each item during each sale?

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6fac/4

```
SELECT t1.itemID
     , t3.color
     , t2.price
  FROM table_1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.itemID = t2.itemID
  LEFT JOIN table_3 t3
    ON t2.colorID = t3.colorID
  LEFT JOIN table_4 t4
    ON t3.colorID = t4.colorID
  WHERE t1.sale_date BETWEEN saleBegin and saleEnd;
```

Comment: Hi Olli, thank you for the answer!  I am running into a problem though.  If there is a null value on the itemID (let's pretend they know something sold, but don't know what, yet still has a sale date) it's not returning.  How can I get that to return as well, even with all the null values?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but this query will give you the itemID, color and price for each product during each sale

```
SELECT
   t4.SaleBegin
  ,t4.SaleEnd
  ,t1.itemID
  ,t3.color
  ,t2.price
FROM Table4 t4
INNER JOIN Table1 t1
  ON t4.SaleBegin = CAST(REPLACE(t1.[sale date], '/', '/1/') AS DATE)
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.itemID = t2.itemID
  AND t4.ColorID = t2.ColorID
INNER JOIN Table3 t3
  ON t4.ColorID = t3.colorID
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c1a4/8)